# Best way to search Ruby syntax in search engine

Tags: ruby

I'd like to know what suggestions there are for Googling (or using other search engines if preferable) for Ruby syntax.  I'm very new, and a substantial part of my baptism by fire comes by way of reading other people's code.  Ruby in particular can be challenging this way-- it's fantastically compact and easy to read if you know how to read it, so to speak.  But figuring that out can be difficult at times.  It's worth it, but difficult.  So, for example, let's say I encounter an expression like this:

```
tquery = "#{MASTER_URL}#{query_str}"
```

Well, apparently there's something going on with the syntax #{stuff}, but what?  A variable being manipulated, it seems?  If you encountered such an expression and didn't know about interpolation/substitution and have no ready access to someone to ask directly, how would you go about Googling that?  That's just an example, of course, but I hope it illustrates the type of problem I'd like to address.

Also, if there are better tags to apply to this post please let me know and I will add.  Thank you.

Comment: Probably worth reading a few introductory texts. _The Well Grounded Rubyist_ is a good intro, others are available.

Comment: As @sagarpandya82 says, tutorials/text books for Ruby will help you more than Google searches. You can't search for something like your `tquery` example but you could search for string interpolation or interpolating variables into strings. The same problem will occur querying about other languages because it's not the specific syntax you want to look up. But, again, tutorials will help you more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use a search engine, not about programming.

Comment: I think of it as how to apply a valuable tool to the improvement of programming.  It's a bit broader than "how to use a search engine".  It also includes what engine would be best to use, and how.  The fact that an upvoted and useful suggestion of an engine has been made supports that.  On the other hand, if you have suggestions on how to improve the question, or a better place or tagset, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Symbolhound is pretty good for this. For example, [here's the search for Ruby's `#{}`](http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%23%7B%7D).

Mind, as you can see from the results, it doesn't necessarily come immediately back and tell you what the notation you searched for is *named*, or how it's *defined*, but it does return some helpful results to get you started. It's especially useful for punctuation-based syntax elements that are difficult or impossible to search for in other search engines.

Comment: Oh, very nice.  I've never used Symbolhound.  Time to explore... Thank you.